# Cron job is not working

Tags: shell-script, logs, cron, scheduling

I have a cron job configured at `var/spool/cron/testuser`, Am calling  `adindex.sh` file from there.

Am getting results when am directly put the command directly in prompt(php and sh), But cron is not processing this one.
I tried to log the cron using `tail -f /var/log/cron` and got:

```
Feb 19 04:05:01 ip-118-139-177-76 CROND[18164]: (inwhosting) CMD (/home/testuser/cronlogs/adindex.sh)
```

Edit: Output for crontab -l

```
MAILTO=""
*/5     *       *       *       *       /home/testuser/cronlogs/adindex.sh
*/5     *       *       *       *       /home/testuser/cronlogs/sendemail.sh
*/5     *       *       *       *       /home/testuser/cronlogs/sendsms.sh
```

Ouput of cat /home/testuser/cronlogs/adindex.sh

```
#wget --user=admin--password=pswd123 http://www.exmaple.com/advertiser/cron/updateindex?cron_key=Inw1234 -O /home/testuser/cronlogs/ad/log_`date "+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M"`.txt

php /var/www/html/exmaple/cron/advt_index.php
php /var/www/html/exmaple/cron/ad_index.php
```

Anybody please tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: There's a typo somewhere in your question is adindex.sh a php script or a shell script. your log shows cron is attempting to execute your command, what does your command look like why do you think it isn't running ?

Comment: My cron job is to index the solr database, and it is not indexing via cron job. I tried this via command line and works fine

Comment: what is the name of your script ? is it a php script or shell script ?

Comment: in main cron page i am giving a shell script adindex.sh, which is for executing some php scripts

Comment: can you [edit] your question to add the result of `cron -l`

Comment: Is `php` in `cron`'s `$PATH`?

Comment: Are you executing the shell script with a php interpreter?

Comment: Fixed the issue. It was "Permission denied" problem from cron

Comment: Since the user has "a cron job configured at var/spool/cron/testuser", it makes me believe they manually edited that file rather than using `crontab -e`. This would explain why some jobs are not running.

Answer (score 2):

You have to execute it using `sh`; 
here is my example

```
MAILTO=user@linuxmental.com
30 11 * * * sh /home/user/backup.sh
30 17 * * * sh /home/user/backup.sh
```

have a look here [cronjob](http://www.linuxmental.com/rsync-local-pc-samba-user-directory-incremental-backup)

Comment: Or `chmod a+x /home/user/backup.sh` (assuming it has a shebang).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue. It was a  permission issue of calling sh files from cron.